# Cambio de valores en particular en mongoDB

Tags: json, mongodb, aggregate, replaceall

Quisiera realizar el cambio de valores en particular en varios documentos para tener homogeneidad de los datos ya que tengo datos en 2019 de "Genero" con M y F, y en el 2020-2021 como Male y Female.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

he querido cambiarlo de la siguiente forma:

```
db.RPM.aggregate([
    {
        $addFields:
        {Genero : {$replaceAll: {input: "$Sex", find:{$literal:"F"}, replacement: "Female"}}
        }
    }
])
```

pero no logro cambiarlo, he quitado el $ de M y F pero lo que consigo es tener lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

he querido hacerlo para los dos géneros de corrido pero obtengo los mismos resultados:

```
var fase13={$addFields:{Sex : {$replaceAll: {input: "$Sex", find:{$literal:"F"}, replacement: "Female"}}}}
var fase14={$addFields:{Genero : {$replaceAll: {input: "$Genero", find:{$literal: "M"}, replacement: "Male"}}}}
db.RPM.aggregate([ fase13])
```

Answer (score 0):

Para hacer el remplazo de los dos géneros de corrido utiliza un [`$switch`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/switch/) de la siguiente manera:

```
db.RPM.aggregate([
    {
        "$addFields": {
            "Sex": {
                "$switch": {
                    "branches": [
                        {"case": {"$eq": ["$Sex", "F"]}, "then": "Female"},
                        {"case": {"$eq": ["$Sex", "M"]}, "then": "Male"}
                    ],
                    "default": "$Sex"
                }
            }
        }
    }
])
```

El código realiza lo siguiente:

- Si el campo es una `F`, entonces colocará `Female`.
- Si el campo es una `M`, entonces colocará `Male`.
- Si no coincide con ninguno de los branches, colocará por defecto el valor del campo `Sex`.

---

Alternativamente puedes usar dos estados en tu pipeline similar a este:

```
db.RPM.aggregate([
    {
        "$addFields": {
           "Sex": {
               "$cond": {
                   "if": {"$eq": ["$Sex", "F"]},
                   "then": "Female",
                   "else": "$Sex"
               }
           }
        }
    }
])
```

Este último remplazará el campo por `Female` si el campo está formado por una `F`.

Comment: Muchas gracias Jaime me ha servido mucho de ayuda

Answer (score 0):

O también si no te quieres complicar con otras cosas puedes ejecutar 2 consultas aparte, una para cambiar de `M` a `Male` y otra para cambiar de `F` a `Female`;

```
db.RPM.update({ gender: "M"},{ $set: { gender: "Male"}},{  multi: true});
db.RPM.update({ gender: "F"},{ $set: { gender: "Female"}},{  multi: true});
```

Comment: Muchas gracias pipe, me ha servido micho de ayuda

Comment: Considera marcar la respuesta como  aceptada, para así ayudar al resto de la comunidad. Saludos.